# Get referenced node fields in twig where reference is on remote node only

Tags: theming, 8

I have a reference field with reference on `node 2` to `node 1`.

On `node 1` I want to find those nodes `node 2` with reference to node 1.

How can I access those in twig?

Answer (score 4):

Your node is unaware of the fact that it is referenced by other nodes. So you need to query the nodes that are referencing your node in a preprocess hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node templates.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $nodes2 = $storage->loadByProperties(['field_reference' => $node->id()]);
  $variables['nodes2'] = $nodes2;
  $variables['#cache']['tags'][] = 'node_list';

}
```

Then you can use the nodes you've found in Twig directly:

```
{% for node2 in nodes2 %}
  <p>This node is referenced by {{ node2.label }} ({{ node2.id }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**Rendering of the nodes**

Or better build a entity view of those nodes by specifying a custom view mode, which you have configured to display the fields you want:

```
if ($nodes2) {
  $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
  $nodes2_rendered = $view_builder->viewMultiple($nodes2, 'custom_view_mode');
  $variables['nodes2_rendered'] = $nodes2_rendered;
}
```

and render those nodes in Twig:

```
{{ nodes2_rendered }}
```

---

Edit:

You can now use a content type specific node_list cache tag to make caching more efficient. See this change record https://www.drupal.org/node/3107058

Comment: That works. Exactly the answer i was looking for.

Comment: On second thought you need to take care of caching, otherwise the render cache will not update when modifying the referencing nodes. I've added a list tag and when you use the rendered nodes you should be OK. Though using an UI only solution, for example Views and EVA, is probably the easier option.